# Can I call retry after retryWhen in rxJS angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to call retry after retryWhen which is not working, how can I call same observable after retryWhen. My code is not reaching retry.

```
getStatuses(statuses : string[]): Observable<IStatus[]> {
    let body = JSON.stringify({ "Statuses": statuses });
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer' + localStorage.getItem("access_token");
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(this._baseUrl + '/statuses/statusesList', body, options)
               .retryWhen(error => this.refreshToken(error)).retry(3)
                .map((res: Response) => {
                    this.inspections = res.json();
                    return this.inspections;
                });
}
```

here is ny refreshToken() function

```
refreshToken(error$:any): Observable<any> {
    return error$.flatMap((err:Error) => {
        console.log("refreshing token");
        const body: string = 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=' + 
                                localStorage.getItem("refresh_token");
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        // Make the refresh call as normal
        return this.http.post('https://loginqa.test.com/as/token.oauth2', body, options)
    }).map((res: Response) => {
             return res.json();

        })

        .do((resp:Response) => {
           var resultsToken=resp.json();
           alert("testing refresh_token");
            localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
            localStorage.removeItem('refresh_token');
            localStorage.setItem("access_token", resultsToken.access_token);
            localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", resultsToken.refresh_token);

}
```

Comment: What does `refreshToken` return?

Comment: @paulpdaniels I updated my question. please check

Comment: can you update to your latest code or create a jsbin showing your error?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `refreshToken` function doesn't actually handle or emit an error. Which is what it would need to do in order to reach the `retry`.

In your `subscribe` block you aren't subscribing to the `throw` operator so the error is never going anywhere.

I would refactor the `refreshToken` so that it actually emits an error if it fails.

```
// Pass in the error stream so you are actually processing when there is an
// exception
refreshToken(error$): Observable<any> {

  return error$.flatMap(err => {
    console.log("refreshing token");
    const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refreshToken');
    const body: string = `grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=${refreshToken}`;
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    // Make the refresh call as normal
    return this.http.post('https://fedqa.test.com/as/token.oauth2', body, options);
  })
  .map(res => res.json())
  .do(resp => {
    // If there is no error, this will emit a next value
    // and which will trigger the retry
    // An error triggers, then this will not run and the retryWhen
    // will skip ahead to the retry operator.
    localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
    localStorage.removeItem('refresh_token');
    localStorage.setItem("access_token", resp.access_token);
    localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", resp.refresh_token);
    localStorage.setItem("expires_in", resp.expires_in);
  });


}
```

Then use it like:

```
.retryWhen(error$ => this.refreshToken(error$)).retry(3);
```

Comment: @user3154990 you are not returning anything from the `map` operator. Then you are trying to call `json()` on the undefined value so your code jumping out of `retryWhen` and going straight to `retry`. You need to do `.map(resp => { return resp.json(); })` if you aren't using inline functions.

Comment: I still get the same error even after returning data in map function..updated my question again...

Comment: You are trying to read `json()` from resp in the `do` but it doesn't have that method, you have already parsed it in map

Comment: @pauldaniels..everything is good but retry is happening infinite number of times ..please see my updated question for calling function

Comment: @pauldaniels ..do I need to call return Observable.Next() from do? This function is executing the error in retry and going into infinite loop..I don't have any control on retry to debug and see...but function is not picking access_token that was returned by refresh_token() method and executing retryWhen again and goining into infinite loop.

Comment: Remove `var resultsToken=resp.json();` from your `do` block

Comment: @pauldaniels no luck.